# Add values of JSON array and display under one array on condition

Tags: angularjs, json

JSON Array as below

```
[{"id":"26","buName":"CAS","totFocCust":23,"totCustResp":10,"totFocProj":160,"totProjResp":13,"wtProjScore":1076.65,"teamSize":246},{"id":"33","buName":"ECO","totFocCust":0,"totCustResp":0,"totFocProj":0,"totProjResp":0,"wtProjScore":0,"teamSize":0},{"id":"28","buName":"DAS","totFocCust":0,"totCustResp":0,"totFocProj":0,"totProjResp":0,"wtProjScore":0,"teamSize":0},{"id":"27","buName":"DCS","totFocCust":9,"totCustResp":0,"totFocProj":31,"totProjResp":0,"wtProjScore":0,"teamSize":0},{"id":"29","buName":"EAS","totFocCust":24,"totCustResp":4,"totFocProj":114,"totProjResp":5,"wtProjScore":434.83,"teamSize":89},{"id":"30","buName":"IMS","totFocCust":9,"totCustResp":0,"totFocProj":25,"totProjResp":0,"wtProjScore":0,"teamSize":0}]
```

I need to add the values of wtProjScore and teamSize where buName is CAS,EAS and DAS and show it in a the same array along with the other buName for eg.; as below.Using angularJS to iterate through the JSON array.

```
[{"id":"2689","buName":"ABS","totFocCust":23,"totCustResp":10,"totFocProj":160,"totProjResp":13,"wtProjScore":1511.48,"teamSize":335},{"id":"33","buName":"CISCO","totFocCust":0,"totCustResp":0,"totFocProj":0,"totProjResp":0,"wtProjScore":0,"teamSize":0},{"id":"27","buName":"DCS","totFocCust":9,"totCustResp":0,"totFocProj":31,"totProjResp":0,"wtProjScore":0,"teamSize":0},{"id":"30","buName":"IMS","totFocCust":9,"totCustResp":0,"totFocProj":25,"totProjResp":0,"wtProjScore":0,"teamSize":0}]
```

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Comment: My try was as below        
       `if(temp=="26" || temp=="28" || temp=="29"){
        temp="2689";
        buName = "ABS";
        wtProjScore += value.wtProjScore;          
        totTeamSize +=value.totTeamSize;                
       }else{
        buName = value.buName;
        wtProjScore=value.wtProjScore;        
              totTeamSize +=value.totTeamSize;        
       }       finalArray.push({"id":temp,"buName":buName,"wtProjScore":wtProjScore,"teamSize":totTeamSize});   });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using a simple `forEach` loop.

```
   var totprojScore = totTeamSize = 0;  
   $scope.newJSONArray = []; //Use this to bind your view.
        yourJSONArray.forEach(function(obj) { 
             if(obj.buName == "CAS" || obj.buName == "EAS" || obj.buName == "DAS"){  
                      totprojScore += obj.wtProjScore ;
                      totTeamSize += obj.teamSize;
                }  
             else{
                 $scope.newJSONArray.push(obj);
              }            
         });

$scope.newJSONArray.push({
  "id":temp,
  "buName":"tempName",
  "wtProjScore":totprojScore ,
  "teamSize":totTeamSize 
});
```

Comment: Even this produces each row in separate lines. I needed the data to be combined if its CAS,EAS or DAS.

Comment: Check the edit. Hope this solves your issue. Please accept this as an answer if it did.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript `filter` and `reduce` to accomplish this:

```js
a = [{"id":"26","buName":"CAS","totFocCust":23,"totCustResp":10,"totFocProj":160,"totProjResp":13,"wtProjScore":1076.65,"teamSize":246},{"id":"33","buName":"ECO","totFocCust":0,"totCustResp":0,"totFocProj":0,"totProjResp":0,"wtProjScore":0,"teamSize":0},{"id":"28","buName":"DAS","totFocCust":0,"totCustResp":0,"totFocProj":0,"totProjResp":0,"wtProjScore":0,"teamSize":0},{"id":"27","buName":"DCS","totFocCust":9,"totCustResp":0,"totFocProj":31,"totProjResp":0,"wtProjScore":0,"teamSize":0},{"id":"29","buName":"EAS","totFocCust":24,"totCustResp":4,"totFocProj":114,"totProjResp":5,"wtProjScore":434.83,"teamSize":89},{"id":"30","buName":"IMS","totFocCust":9,"totCustResp":0,"totFocProj":25,"totProjResp":0,"wtProjScore":0,"teamSize":0}]

function check(x){
  return x.buName == "CAS" || x.buName == "EAS" || x.buName == "DAS";
}
b = a.filter((x)=>{return check(x)})

c = b.reduce((x,y)=>{return x+y.wtProjScore},0)

d = b.reduce((x,y)=>{return x+y.teamSize},0)

console.log("For CAS, EAS, DAS:")
console.log("Total wtProjScore: ",c)
console.log("Total teamSize: ",d)
```

Clarify your requirements if you want it to be presented differently. Or you can adjust this code yourself for your needs

Comment: This is good to go if I have to only display the data on log.But my requirement is to reform the array with the result and pass it to the scope element to the view. The result array is displayed in my question.